# Can I write a commentary on my own article?

Tags: publications, phd

I have just finished writing an article for my PhD. In the discussion section of this article, there is a paragraph where I mention a tangential discovery based on the main findings of the article. It doesn't fit well with the main article, and so my supervisors are recommending that I remove it. However I want to publish this tangential finding, as it is potentially even more important than the main article. But because it isn't directly related to my PhD, I won't have the time to flesh it out into a full article.

Is it possible for me to write a commentary on my own published article, and publish that separately? I would be able to summarize the tangential finding in about 1000 words, and it would allow me to claim the idea even if I can't fully flesh it out at this time.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: removed final question as it was irrelevant

Comment: Do you have a fully worked idea significant enough to merit independent publication, that fits in 1000 words, and that your advisor(s) aren't stoked about? I'd urge you to consider if instead you have very nice preliminary data for a future study that you'd like to do in the future. I've had nice ideas I haven't managed to get into a paper for > 5 years...I could blog about them, but if someone did the actual work without me after reading it they'd get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write such an article and *seek to have it published*. But it is up to the publisher whether it will be published or rejected. The usual standard calls for some significance and/or innovation in a new publication and you may meet that standard or not.

But the decision is theirs, not yours.

It is more likely to be publishable if you expand it sufficiently that it stands alone in some sense. If a reader of the original would find the new work obvious, then it is unlikely to meet the standard.

---

Your final question about publishers is off topic here as a "shopping question", so I've ignored that. Perhaps you should remove it.